# Problems using FileInputStream and a File object in place of a named pipe

Tags: android, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I'm using a DataStream wrapping a FileStream to send Large Bitmaps between two different apps (Intents have a 1mb limit and I don't want to save the files to the file system),

My problem is the [DataInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) is throwing an `EOFException` when the stream is still open but there is no data. I expected this to simply block (Although the Documentation is helpfully quite vague on the matter).

DataOutputStream:

```
public void onEvent() {
    fos.writeInt(width);
    fos.writeInt(height);
    fos.writeInt(newBuffer.length);
    fos.write(newBuffer);
}
```

DataInputStream:

```
while(true) {
    int width = fis.readInt();
    int height = fis.readInt();
    int length = fis.readInt();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    fis.read(bytes);
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better set of classes to Stream data from one Thread to another (Where, read() / readInt() successfully blocks).

**EDIT**

I've tried to iron this out by removing `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` from the equation by simply using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`:

```
    fos.write(intToByteArray(width));
    fos.write(intToByteArray(height));
    fos.write(intToByteArray(newBuffer.length));
    Log.e(this.class.getName(), "Writing width: " + Arrays.toString(intToByteArray(width)) + 
                                                      ", height: " + Arrays.toString(intToByteArray(height)) + 
                                                      ", length: " + Arrays.toString(intToByteArray(newBuffer.length)));
    fos.write(newBuffer);
    if(repeat == -1) {
        Log.e(this.class.getName(), "Closing ramFile");
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
```

which gives:

`Writing width: [0, 0, 2, -48], height: [0, 0, 5, 0], length: [0, 56, 64, 0]`

and on the other side I use this:

```
while(true) {
    byte[] intByteArray = new byte[] { -1,-1,-1,-1 };
    fis.read(intByteArray);
    Log.e(this.class.getName(), Arrays.toString(intByteArray));
    int width = toInt(intByteArray, 0);
    fis.read(intByteArray);
    int height = toInt(intByteArray, 0);
    fis.read(intByteArray);
    int length = toInt(intByteArray, 0);
    Log.e(this.class.getName(), "Reading width: " + width + ", height: " + height + ", length: " + length);
}
```

Which gives:

```
[0, 0, 2, -48] 
Reading width: 720, height: 1280, length: 3686400
```

and then bizarrely, `read()` doesn't block and it just carries on merrily, not blocking but not filling any values in the array (initialising the array to { 9, 9, 9, 9 } is still 9, 9, 9, 9 after the read).

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1] 
Reading width: -1, height: -1, length: -1 
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1
```

Is this what being crazy feels like?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple answer here (Which is not very well documented).

The FileInputStream has no timeout for it's `read` request - meaning that if you read from an empty but not closed stream it will return without filling in the bytes (leaving the bytes given "as is").

You can use `LocalSocket` and `LocalServerSocket` to stream data through the same mechanism and use

```
LocalServerSocket server = new LocalServerSocket(SOCKET_NAME);
LocalSocket socket = server.accept();
socket.setSoTimeout(60);
```

which will force a 60 second timeout on you're read operation (blocking until data is available).